# i get a .getDateEditor Error

Tags: java, swing, date, windowbuilder

Im trying to add a `JDateChooser` to my gui that then inserts the data into my data base. I keep getting this error for the `.getDataEditor`,

> The method getDateEditor() is undefined for the type JTextField

I cant figure out how to make it work so if anyone can help me plz do so.

I will paste the part of the code I'm having trouble with i can post the whole code which is like 300+ lines if need.

```
btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try{
            String query = "insert into Oilform (LastName, MI, FirstName, StreetAddress, City, Make, Model, CarYear, PhoneNumber, Mileage, Date) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            java.sql.PreparedStatement pst= con.prepareStatement(query);

            pst.setString(1, textField.getText());
            pst.setString(2, textField_1.getText());
            pst.setString(3, textField_2.getText());
            pst.setString(4, textField_3.getText());
            pst.setString(5, textField_4.getText());
            //Combo Boxes States
            //String value=statesComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //pst.setString(6, value);
            //pst.setString(6, (String)statesComboBox.getSelectedItem());

            pst.setString(6, textField_5.getText());
            pst.setString(7, textField_6.getText());
            pst.setString(8, textField_7.getText());
            pst.setString(9, textField_8.getText());
            pst.setString(10,textField_9.getText());
            pst.setString(11, ((JTextField)Date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());

            //pst.setString(13, (String)comboBox.getSelectedItem());
            //Combo Boxes Oil Types
            //String value1=comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //pst.setString(13, value1);

            pst.execute();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Saved");

            pst.execute();
        }catch(Exception i) {
                System.err.println("Exception: " + i.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, that's kind of a mess.  Why note use `Date.getDate()` and format the `Date` value with a `DateFormatter` instead...

Comment: From your error message, `Date` doesn't seem to be a `JDateChooser` but is a `JTextField`...

Comment: I dont really know how to do that and i want the date sent to my databse when i click submit and have the current date inserted into the database can i still do that with "Date.getDate()" and when i Change it to JDateChooser the error goes away but when i run it i get "Exception: null"

Comment: That's kind of my point...`new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD").format(Date.getDate())` will result in a much simpler solution...

Comment: How would i put that into my code could you show me? becuase im a little confused

Answer (score 1):

This is database specific as some database will need the date in specific format...

You might be able to use something like...

```
pst.setString(11, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD").format(Date.getDate()));
```

This assumes that the database column is text and that `Date`is actually a `JDateChooser` and not a `JTextField`, which I suspect it is...

A better solution would be to make the database column some kind of DATE column, the you could just use something like...

```
pst.setDate(11, new java.sql.Date(Date.getDate().getTime()));
```

And let the JDBC driver and database work it all out...

Comment: I tried that but i still get a "Exception: null" error... any idea why?

Comment: Something is null...I have no context from which I can suggest more  other then check all your references...